# Retrieve member_id with MailChimp 3.0 and Gibbon 2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, ruby-on-rails-4.2, gibbon

In my app's user settings, a user can subscribe or unsubscribe to a MailChimp list by checking a box. I am having some trouble retrieving the users MailChimp member_id.

I created a .env file with:

```
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = "my_api_key"
MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID = "my_list_id"
```

I created an initializer called gibbon.rb with:

```
Gibbon::Request.api_key = ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"]
Gibbon::Request.timeout = 15
```

I use this method in the user.rb

```
def mailchimp_news
  @mailchimp_list_id = ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"]
  @gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new
  if self.news_email == true
    @gibbon.lists(@mailchimp_list_id).members.update(body: {
    email_address: self.email,
    status: "subscribed",
    merge_fields: {FNAME: self.name,
                   LNAME: ""}
    })
  elsif self.news_email == false
    @gibbon.lists(@mailchimp_list_id).members(member_id).update(body: { status: "unsubscribed" })
end
```

end

And call it with an after check

```
after_save :mailchimp_news
```

I receive this error: `` undefined local variable or method `member_id' ``. How do I get the member_id?

Comment: You have an error in your Ruby code, and an error is being raised before a call to the Mailchimp API is being made. You're referring to a variable or method named `member_id` and that's not defined. The first step is to fix this bug.

Answer (score 10):

From the [How To Manage Subscribers](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/how-to-manage-subscribers) help page, in API v3 the subscriber ID is the MD5 hash of the lower case version of the user's email address.

So you'll want to use `Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.email.downcase)`.